# Software/script to calculate the computational complexity of code?

Tags: algorithm

Does anyone know of any program/script to calculate the computational complexity of code (e.g. method function) automatically?

If not, is there a good way (e.g. a design pattern, algorithm, etc) that supports it?

I'm not trying to do this in general.

In most cases, I know the input, the algorithm running it, and what constitutes a halt. I'm trying to compare 2 or more algorithms this way.

E.g.

```
algo #1 - 2x^2 + 10x + 5

algo #2 - 5x^2 + 1x + 3
```

Both algorithms are O(N^2). But algo #2 is better in the short run, while algo #1 is better in the long run.

Comment: Do you mean 'is there a program which reads the source code for a function and writes an equation for the computational complexity of that function' ?  That seems to be the thrust of your first sentence, but the rest of your question confuses me.  Ah ha, I'm not the only one confused.

Comment: Also, are you looking for the theoretical computational complexity or the empirical computational complexity?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Thank you Katriel... when I read this question It sounded really familiar, but I didnt remembered where it was.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A tool for calculating the big-O time complexity of Java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958299/a-tool-for-calculating-the-big-o-time-complexity-of-java-code)

Comment: This seems an interesting question

Answer (score 1):

While it is impossible to develop an algorithm that solves your problem generally, you can write an algorithm that will calculate the complexity of a piece of software for a few example inputs.

The only software I can find reference to is called [Trend-Profiler](http://trend-prof.tigris.org/). But, if you are more interested in the algorithm than the result, there is a paper [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs295/papers/trend-prof.pdf) that describes the software and its algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to sample an algorithm with a different amount of inputs?
With the time calculated for each input, you could approximate the complexity function and therefore determine whichever algorithm is better and at which stage.