# Big-O notation of a function in Java by experiment

Tags: java, big-o, heuristics

I need to write a program that determines the Big-O notation of an algorithm in Java.

I don't have access to the algorithms code, so it must be based on experimentation and execution times. I don't know where to start.

Can someone help me?

Edit: The only thing i know about the algorithm is that takes an integer value and doesn't have a return

Comment: This appears to be a homework. If it is, well, you are expected to figure out the solution by yourself. You likely were given the knowledge to do this. If you don't know where to start, then try harder.

Comment: what  ????? i have never heard of program that can determines big oh. Thats analysis you have to perform yourself by running the algorithm with different inputs

Comment: @Moh123 That's not an analysis, that's a simulation. An analysis requires math.

Comment: You can start by explaining the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to whoever came up with this idea. Also, the Big-O notation values are always parametrized with *something*. How do you determine that "something" without knowing anything about the algorithm/program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to be aware that what such a program does it to provided an evidence-based guess as to what complexity class the algorithm belongs to.  It can give the wrong answer.  (Indeed, in complicated cases where the complexity class is unusual, wrong answers are increasingly likely.)

In short, this is NOT complexity analysis.

The general approach would be:

- Run the algorithm multiple times with values of N across the range, measuring the execution times.  Repeat multiple times for each N, to ensure that you are getting consistent measurements.
- Try to fit the experimental results to different kinds of curves; i.e. linear, quadratic, logarithmic.  Note that it is the fit for large values of N that matters.  So when you check for "goodness of fit", use a measure that gives increasing weight to the larger data points.

This is intended as a start point. For example, I'm expecting that you will do your own research on issues such as:

- how to get *reliable* execution-time measurements (for Java),
- how to do curve fitting in a *mathematically sound* way, and
- dealing with the case where the execution times get too long to measure experimentally for large N.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i'm trying to do. But, how i fit the experimental results whith the diferent types of curves automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You could do some experiments and graph the amount of input vs the time spent executing the function. Then you could compare it to the well known curves associated with Big-O or try to estimate the equation.

Comment: That's what i'm doing now, but i need to determine it automatically

Comment: there is no way to do it automatically

Comment: refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958299/a-tool-for-calculating-the-big-o-time-complexity-of-java-code

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have access to the algorithm's source code, the only thing you can do is to measure how long the algorithm takes for inputs of different size, and then try to extrapolate a function from that. Since you are doing experiments, you now enter the field of statistics, so maybe you can use ideas from that area, such as [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis).