# How can I automate calculation of time complexity of algorithms in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, time-complexity, big-o

Is there an inbuild method in JavaScript for calculating time complexity of algorithms?

For instance, if I feed in this function:

```
function solution(A) {
    let smallestInt = 1;

    function existsInArray(val) {
        return A.find((a) => a === val);
    }

    for (let index = smallestInt; index < 1000000; index++) {
        if (existsInArray(index) && !existsInArray(index + 1) &&
            existsInArray(smallestInt)) {
            smallestInt = index + 1
        }
    }
    return smallestInt;
}
```

The method should be able to tell me that the time complexity of the algorithm is **O(N*2)** or whichever correct answer would be?

If no inbuild method is available, is there a library with automated methods for achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

No. Such a program would solve the [halting problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Which is impossible.

Comment: you posted an invalid link

Comment: @eugen thanks, fixed (hvala brate)

Answer (score 1):

Generally no, though one could run multiple simulations on different inputs to come up with a reasonable approximation.

See these three useful discussions:

1. [Are runtime bounds in P decidable? (answer: no)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/are-runtime-bounds-in-p-decidable-answer-no#comment40524_14969)
2. [Programmatically obtaining Big-O efficiency of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480775/programmatically-obtaining-big-o-efficiency-of-code)
3. [A tool for calculating the big-O time complexity of Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958299/a-tool-for-calculating-the-big-o-time-complexity-of-java-code)

Comment: Those are some useful links there. Thanks.

Following up on these resources provide a general gist that there is no library (yet) that could achieve what am looking for. 

But the search is not complete. I would want to know how platforms such as [codility](https://app.codility.com/programmers/) performs automatic time-complexity for algorithms written on the platform.