# Generating also non-unique (duplicated) permutations

Tags: c, permutation, combinatorics

I've written a basic permutation program in C.
The user types a number, and it prints all the permutations of that number.

Basically, this is how it works (the main algorithm is the one used to [find the next higher permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9368205/1380370)):

```
int currentPerm = toAscending(num);
int lastPerm = toDescending(num);
int counter = 1;

printf("%d", currentPerm);

while (currentPerm != lastPerm)
{
   counter++;
   currentPerm = nextHigherPerm(currentPerm);
   printf("%d", currentPerm);
}
```

However, when the number input includes repeated digits - duplicates - some permutations are not being generated, since they're duplicates. The counter shows a different number than it's supposed to - Instead of showing the factorial of the number of digits in the number, it shows a smaller number, of only unique permutations.

For example:

```
num = 1234567
counter = 5040 (!7 - all unique)

num = 1123456
counter = 2520

num = 1112345
counter = 840
```

I want to it to treat repeated/duplicated digits as if they were different - I don't want to generate only *unique* permutations - but rather generate *all* the permutations, regardless of whether they're repeated and duplicates of others.

Comment: If you're asking how to change the code that generates the permutations, don't you think it'd be wise to show the code that does the generating? Right now you're only showing a call to a function: `nextHigherPerm(currentPerm)`.

Comment: @Caleb I didn't include it because it's pretty long. I thought I could get some direction about what I should change/pay attention to in the `findHigherPerm` algorithm, so I will not ignore un-unique permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... why not just calculate the factorial of the length of the input string then? ;)

Comment: I want to show all the permutations in that process, so I can't simply use !digits to calculate it. I want to also show duplicated permutations - not only unique ones - if there are ones.

Comment: So the simple answer is this: create a new string, with the same length as the input, and with no repeating entries. Then create a mapping between the new and old strings; generate the permutations on the new string and for each permutation map it back. e.g. If input is 76444321 create 12345678, with 1 mapping to 7, 2 mapping to 6, 3 mapping to 4 (the "first" four), 4 mapping to four (the "second" four) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to it to treat repeated/duplicated digits as if they were
>   different - I don't want to calculate only the number of unique
>   permutations.

If the only information that `nextHigherPerm()` uses is the number that's passed in, you're out of luck. Consider `nextHigherPerm(122)`. How can the function know how many versions of `122` it has already seen? Should `nextHigherPerm(122)` return `122` or `212`? There's no way to know unless you keep track of the current state of the generator separately.

Answer (score 1):

When you have 3 letters for example ABC, you can make: `ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA`, 6 combinations (6!). If 2 of those letters repeat like AAB, you can make: AAB, ABA, BAA, IT IS NOT 3! so What is it? From where does it comes from? The real way to calculate it when a digit or letter is repeated is with combinations -> `( n k ) = n! / ( n! * ( n! - k! ) )`

Let's make another illustrative example: `AAAB`, then the possible combinations are `AAAB, AABA, ABAA, BAAA` only four combinations, and if you calcualte them by the formula `4C3 = 4.`

How is the correct procedure to generate all these lists:

- Store the digits in an array. Example `ABCD`.
- Set the 0 element of the array as the pivot element, and exclude it from the temp array. `A {BCD}`
- Then as you want all the combinations (Even the repeated), move the elements of the temporal array to the right or left (However you like) until you reach the n element.

> A{BCD}------------A{CDB}------------A{DBC}

- Do the second step again but with the temp array.

> A{B{CD}}------------A{C{DB}}------------A{D{BC}}

- Do the third step again but inside the second temp array.

> A{B{CD}}------------A{C{DB}}------------A{D{BC}}
>
> A{B{DC}}------------A{C{BD}}------------A{D{CB}}

- Go to the first array and move the array, `BCDA`, set B as pivot, and do this until you find all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert it to a string then treat your program like an anagram generator?