# Next Biggest Number Same Digits

Tags: python, integer

I don't see anything wrong with my code but I can't seem to return -1 when the input cannot produce a next bigger number, i.e. input of `531` which is descending.

```
import itertools as it
def next_bigger(n):
    if sorted("531", reverse = True) == list("531"):
        return -1
    s = tuple(str(n))
    for x in it.dropwhile(lambda x: x <= s, it.permutations(sorted(s))):
        return int(''.join(x))
    return s
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve what you want so far? It's much better for you to have a go and show your efforts; questions that don't do this are usually poorly received here.

Comment: see revised code above.

Comment: `if True:` will _always_ be True.  What condition do you really want to check?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use an `if` statement at the beginning of your function to test whether the number is already in reverse sorted order. If it is sorted `return -1` straight away:

```
>>> sorted("531", reverse = True) == list("531")
True
```

Comment: at what line would i place this conditional statement?

Comment: @Mr.Jibz the first line after you define the function

Comment: when i do that (which is in edited code above), output reads "-1 should equal 21," 21 being the first test output with an input of 12.

Comment: Well it needs to be `if sorted(str(n), reverse = True) == list(str(n)):`. you can't pass `531` every time of course

Comment: Don't use his literal example of "531".  Use the actual input to the function.

Comment: makes sense, yes. now my problem is run time, ugh.

Comment: "Process was terminated. It took longer than 8000ms to complete"

Comment: Why are you calling `permutations()`?

Comment: my logic was that it would generate permutations of the same digits in order, which returning the first permutation that is greater than the input

Comment: @Mr.Jibz Brute force approach is not the best, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368205/given-a-number-find-the-next-higher-number-which-has-the-exact-same-set-of-digi and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115609/next-bigger-number-with-the-same-digits

Comment: Would it work to start by permuting only a few rightmost digits instead of the whole number?