# Digit swap wrong examples

Tags: algorithm

[swap digit problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368205/given-a-number-find-the-next-higher-number-which-has-the-exact-same-set-of-digi)

This problem is screwing with my mind because of the examples.

If I have:

```
38276
```

Then the next biggest is

```
87632
```

But the problem points it out as the next biggest being `38627`

I don't understand what the output should be?

Answer (score 1):

38276 < 38627 < 87632

So your suggestion of 87632 cannot be next biggest. As the comment section of the linked problem suggests, look at C++ next_permute.

If it helps, think of this as the next alphabetical ordered solution. I.e. if you have abc, (next biggest) the next alphabetic order will be acb.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to find the **next** highest number not the **highest** number as you are currently thinking.

If the initial number `n` is `38276` the next highest number `m` would be `38627` since there is no number `k` that can be formed from the initial digits such that `n < k < m`.

Answer (score 1):

The Next highest number is surely `38627` not `87632`. Using a brute force method, you can find all permutations of the number then sort it.  equivalent of the logic in c++ is `next_permutation` function